# .ipa file from xcode, encrypted

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.2, anti-piracy

I want to test a piece of anti-piracy code.

The problem is, Crackulous detects only apps that have been downloaded from the appstore, because the have an encryption.

Is there any way to test it on a device?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/). This is used to deploy application to test devices with regular certificates.

Comment: tried it. it also doesn't recognizing the downloaded app from testflight. I know that crackulous detects only apps that have been downloaded from the appstore, but I'm looking for another solution...